# Text in Markdown popups not always clear with new meta theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Using the GUI buttons for inserting a link in the markdown editor on meta, the text in the pop-up is too similar in colour to the background:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

This also seems to be the case with the image-upload pop-up too (I presume it's a common style sheet issue).

Comment: I'm fixing this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Thanks again, Jin. You're really super!