# markdown help page on meta.photo.SE is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help has some of the same CSS issues as this older thread about the popups: [Text in Markdown popups not always clear with new meta theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/text-in-markdown-popups-not-always-clear-with-new-meta-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good catch. I have put in a fix, will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Thanks Jin! You rock as usual!!