# Anchored section's highlighting in the markdown help won't fade away completely (except for #code)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The problem might be strongly related to: [markdown help page on meta.photo.SE is unreadable](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/861/markdown-help-page-on-meta-photo-se-is-unreadable)

If one goes to an anchor link that points to a section in the [markdown help](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), the section's highlighting won't fade away completely. It does fade a little from more saturated yellow, but still leaves the text rather unreadable.

For example [comment formatting](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

[image: commenting help]

… whereas [code and preformatted text](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) help (and only code and preformatted text section, it seems) fades away properly:

[image: code and preformatted text]

---

The problem occurs with Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera—at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior (copying the item up top) and highlighting are [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), *however* that highlight/background color looks like crap on a dark background site like photgraphy.

In the next build we're giving it some love:

[image: Pictar!]

*Edit:* This is now complete.

Comment: Good that an improvement is coming. However, regarding status-bydesign...to @koiyu's point, the highlight is not actually fully fading out...it fades out part way, then stops, and stays mostly highlighted. I would assume that partial fading is NOT actually by-design...and is some kind of flaw in the script that does the fading.

Comment: @jrista - It was *fully* fading...it was just fading to a color that *appeared* to hang half way (between the yellow it started with and white...not a script error)...but that color is the intended color for all light-background sites, for example:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#editing